# How to transfer cookies from default browser to selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

out there. Right now I have the problem that I want some logins from my cookies to my selenium chrome browser.

I have done some tests, with no luck.

That is why I am asking here. `Anyone know how to transfer cookies, from my default browser to my selenium webdriver browser?`

My code looks like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import getpass
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\rober\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\rober\Desktop\Bot\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.zalando.dk/jordan-air-jordan-1-mid-sneakers-high-joc12n001-a18.html")

buyButton = False

while buyButton is False:

    try:
        
        addToCartBtn = addButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/x-wrapper-re-1-6/div/div[4]/button')

        print("Varen er udsolgt")

        time.sleep(1)
        driver.refresh()

    except:
        addToCartBtn = addButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="picker-trigger"]')

        print("Varen er på Lager")
        buyButton = True

while buyButton is True:
    time.sleep(1)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.uc-btn#uc-btn-accept-banner"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Vælg størrelse']"))).click()
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'size-picker')]//span[text()='51.5']"))))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'size-picker')]//span[text()='51.5']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Læg i indkøbskurv']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title="Indkøbskurv"]'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".z-coast-base__totals-tile .z-1-button__content"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title="Registrér dig"]'))).click()
```

If anyone has an idea or a suggestion on how I do it then you are more than welcome to write.

Comment: Looks like you're doing it correctly.  You just need to set the profile to the one that already has the cookies.  Note that session cookies will be per session.

Comment: @pcalkins What is called Default should be the one with the login cookie I need. But I'm not quite sure. Is there a way I can check it?

Comment: inspector should list cookies as well as session and local storage.

Answer (score 0):

#### On the browser

- Open up devtools
- Go to network tab and keep an eye on it
- When you login identify the appropriate request
- Left on the copy value > copy as curl

[image]

#### Extracting the cookies

- Go to https://curlconverter.com/
- Select Python
- Paste the curl command on the input section

Now you will get a Python code snippet that is designed for the `request` library. You will get the headers, the cookies and the params to build the URL.

Copy the cookie information from there paste it in your Selenium code.

Comment: it's not working...
it could result in:
`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'name'`